# C# Saving feet and inches as a decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

After two days of getting confused and trying numerous different ways I have reluctantly come here for some advice (reluctant because I feel I should have worked this out).

I am trying to save feet and inch values as decimals.

I allow the user to enter a width of a room in feet and inches and try to convert it to a decimal value.

If I enter `width feet: 10` `width inches: 10` I expect `330.2` to be saved to my database, then when I reload the page I expect `width feet: 10` `width inches: 10` to be displayed.

My problem is that in my viewmodel I try to assign a value to `WidthImperial` for each room but it gets set to `[0] = 108333.0` and `[1] = 4.0`. Nothing gets saved to the database because this issue causes the `Width` parameter to be out of range.

What am I doing wrong any help an dadvice is really appriciated.

I am using asp mvc 4 with entity framework.

**My Code**

Rooms.cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Rooms[i].WidthImperial[0], null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Width ft" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Rooms[i].WidthImperial[1], null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Width inches" })
```

MyController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TakeOn(TakeOn to)
{
    ...Other Stuff
    properties = Session["properties"] as List<Property>;
    _Property = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyID == to.PropertyID);
    _Property = to.MapToProperty(_Property, UOW);
    ...Other stuff
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class TakeOn
{
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }

    //maps the view model to the property class
    public BL.Property MapToProperty(BL.Property property, UnitOfWork uow)
    {
        ...some other stuff
        property.Rooms = SetRooms(property);
        ...some other stuff
    }

    ICollection<Room> SetRooms(BL.Property property)
    {
        foreach (Room rm in this.Rooms)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rm.Title) || rm.Images.Count > 0)
            {
                Room room = property.Rooms.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoomID == rm.RoomID);//get room if it exists in db
                if (room == null)
                {
                    room = new Room();//create new room and add to property
                    room.Images = new List<BL.Image>();
                    property.Rooms.Add(room);
                }

                room.WidthImperial = thisRoom.WidthImperial;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Room.cs (EF model)

```
public partial class Room
{
    ...other properties
    public Nullable<decimal> Width { get; set; }
    ...other properties
}
```

Room.cs (additional properties)

```
public partial class Room
{
    public List<double> WidthImperial
    {
        get
        {
            double centimetres = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width * 100);
            double totalInches = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(centimetres / 2.54)); // This will take a floor function of Centimetres/2.54
            double feet = (totalInches - totalInches % 12) / 12; // This will make it divisible by 12
            double inches = totalInches % 12; // This will give you the remainder after you divide by 12
            return new List<double> { feet, inches };
        }
        set
        {
            //convert value to inches
            double feet = value[0];
            double inches = value[1];
            inches += feet * 12;
            this.Width = (decimal)inches * 2.54m;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple - go metric! ;) - But joke aside, why do you no only integer-divide the `totalInches / 12` - this is always rounded down and should fit the task pretty well...

Comment: Why do you say, that when you enter "width feet: 10 width inches: 10", you "expect 330.2"?

Comment: @KirkWoll, OP means convert to centimetres.

Comment: Do you want the user to enter the width in feet and inches in the view, but the store the converted value (centimetres) in the database?

Comment: It seems like you should be able to just set breakpoints and figure out where your math or datatype conversions has gone wrong.  A couple of observations: It looks like you're dealing in metres in the getter and centimetres in the setter.  I would also avoid using Lists here and use named properties WidthInches and WidthFeet, if only to make debugging and maintenance easier.  Lastly, you have to set the decimal value from two different sources: the database and postback.  Only one of those sources requires a conversion.  I don't think that's shown in the code?